# What is the meaning of `ls directory > something`

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, redirect

I don't understand the meaning of this command.

```
ls ../slc > dates
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will generate a list of the folders and the files inside the `slc` folder and create a file named `dates` and enter there.

For example I have a folder named git and I have 3 folders there. If I go inside the git folder using terminal and enter the command:

```
ls ../git > dates.txt
```

It will create a text file in the same directory named dates.txt and enter all the name of the files and folders inside that directory in that file. This is what my dates.txt file looks like after I entered the command:

```
build-KE3600_APP-Desktop-Default
dates.txt
KE3600_APP
vlc
```